# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space creating a long list of Myclass

Tags: java, memory, serialization, heap-memory

I'm parsing some data from internet to create an arraylist where every Politician class has a field HashMap. Every HashMap will contains 132*150 entry. After the 164th map filled I got this exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
I wanted to store this big list using serialization to use it in the future.
How should I proceed? Should I serialize Politician instances and not the whole list? Is there any other optimal way to store this data?
(If needed) I'm writing this data also into files. I thinked to store the data "as object" to improve the ease of use.
Some code:

```
private static void setVotiParlamentari(ParserOpenParlamento parser, ArrayList<Politician> politicianList){
for(Politician p : politicianList){
    String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "io_files" + File.separator + "info_parlamentari2";
    String filename = File.separator + p.getName() + ".txt";
    Iterator<String> votesIterator = parser.parsePoliticianVotes(p).iterator();
    FileWriter w = null;
    try {
        w = new FileWriter(filepath+filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(w));
    while (votesIterator.hasNext()){
        String vote = votesIterator.next();
        // i.e. for String vote = 35521:08/11/2016:Favorevole:SCCI-MAIE Favorevole:APPROVATA:391
        String tokens[] = vote.split(parser.getSplittingChar());
        String idVote = tokens[0];
        String dateVot = tokens[1];
        String politicianVote = tokens[2];
        String groupVote = tokens[3];
        String result = tokens[4];
        String difference = tokens[5];
        wr.write(idVote+":"+dateVot+":"+politicianVote+":"+groupVote+":"+result+":"+difference+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        p.getVotazioni().put(Integer.parseInt(idVote), new Votazione(idVote, dateVot, politicianVote, groupVote, result, difference));
    }
    wr.close();
}
```

}

Comment: It would be better if you could show a [mcve] of your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Eclipse IDE:

Right mouse click on
`Run As - Run Configuration - Arguments - Vm Arguments`, then add this (for increment Java heap memory size, you also choose other value)

```
-Xmx2048m
```

If you use command line, you add to the tail:

```
-Xmx2048
```

(`2048` is the maximum size of heap memory, you also choose other value)

Answer (score 0):

estimate how much memory your java program need, if it is not more than the memory of you PC then you can give more memory to your program through `JVM Parameter`, else you need to `change your algorithm`.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -Xmx2048m <file-name>.jar
```

`-Xmx2048m` is the heapsize you allocated for java, just resize it as needed

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this solution asap. (the execution takes about 30 hours)

Answer (score 0):

**You are using lots of `String` objects which will potentially cause the memory issues**, so I have modified the code as shown below, which will try to reduce the heap space usage and run better:

```
private static void setVotiParlamentari(ParserOpenParlamento parser, ArrayList<Politician> politicianList) {

 final String DELIMITER = ":";

 for(Politician p : politicianList){
    String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "io_files" + File.separator + "info_parlamentari2";
    String filename = File.separator + p.getName() + ".txt";
    Iterator<String> votesIterator = parser.parsePoliticianVotes(p).iterator();
    FileWriter w = null;

    try {
        w = new FileWriter(filepath+filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(w));

    StringBuffer sb = null;
    String tokens[] = null;
    String vote = null;

    while (votesIterator.hasNext()){

        vote = votesIterator.next();
        // i.e. for String vote = 35521:08/11/2016:Favorevole:SCCI-MAIE Favorevole:APPROVATA:391

        tokens[] = vote.split(parser.getSplittingChar());

        sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(tokens[0]);
        sb.append(DELIMITER);
        sb.append(tokens[1]);
        sb.append(DELIMITER);
        sb.append(tokens[2]);
        sb.append(DELIMITER);
        sb.append(tokens[3]);
        sb.append(DELIMITER);
        sb.append(tokens[4]);
        sb.append(DELIMITER);
        sb.append(tokens[5]);
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        wr.write(sb.toString());

        p.getVotazioni().put(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]), new Votazione(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3], tokens[4], tokens[5]));
    }
    wr.close();
}
```

Along with this, you might need to increase the JVM heap size `-Xmx2048m`